# Azure Sample 4-1-MyOrg throws "HttpRequestException: Invalid status code in the HttpResponseMessage: Unauthorized." Error

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

Found very few direct hits on this issue with this sample.  Either the sample is relative new or updated and no one has tried it or I am clearly doing something incorrect. Running this in Windows 10 using the latest VSCode.  I am new to Azure (recently certified in Fundamentals) and somewhat new to the .Net world.  Both could be working against me.

I have followed the instructions found [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg) multiple times but get the same result.  The full stack trace, FWIW, is

```html
TodoListClient.Services.TodoListService.GetAsync() in TodoListService.cs

                throw new HttpRequestException($"Invalid status code in the HttpResponseMessage: {response.StatusCode}.");

TodoListClient.Controllers.TodoListController.Index() in TodoListController.cs

                return View(await _todoListService.GetAsync());

lambda_method(Closure , object )
Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutorAwaitable+Awaiter.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter<TResult>.GetResult()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask<IActionResult> actionResultValueTask)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ExceptionContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I know what it is complaining about, I just don't know where to go fix it.  I am not sure but I suspect it has something to do with this setup instruction for scope when the app is registered:

**Begin steps:**

Select Add a scope button open the Add a scope screen and Enter the values as indicated below:

For Scope name, use access_as_user.

Select Admins and users options for Who can consent?.

For Admin consent display name type Access TodoListService-aspnetcore-webapi.

For Admin consent description type Allows the app to access TodoListService-aspnetcore-webapi as the signed-in user.

For User consent display name type Access TodoListService-aspnetcore-webapi.

For User consent description type Allow the application to access TodoListService-aspnetcore-webapi on your behalf.

Keep State as Enabled.

Select the Add scope button on the bottom to save this scope.

**End steps**

The thing that I couldn't do was to follow the "Select Admins and users options for Who can consent?." step because there IS no option for selecting "Admins and Users" only "Admins"  Is that the issue here?  I have gone through the steps multiple times and I cannot solve the error.  When I sign in I see the initial web page but when I click on the "TodoList" link, I get the Unauthorized" error.

I created a new user within the new Tenant I created but neither it, not my global admin user can access the "Todolist" App.

What did I miss? Does anyone have this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the sample code and get it works on my side, this is my Azure AD App configs:

***For service Azure AD APP config:***

**App ID**: `a6b73b06-450a-4fac-a7bb-569c3644594c`

**Exponse an API:**
[image]

***For client Azure AD APP config:***

**App ID**: `d2a53db5-da38-47b7-97f1-2d27a9dd056d`

**Auth config:**
[image]

**API required permissions:**
[image]

**create a client secret:**
[image]

Service project `applications.json` settings:

[image]

Client project `applications.json` settings:
[image]

**Result**:
[image]

Comment: Let me know if you have any further questions

Comment: So, there were two approaches to registering the app:  One was automation, which I did not use.  The second was to manually add the registration, which I followed only because I am in learning mode and wanted to actually do the steps.  Did you use the Powershell script to register the app?

Comment: Going to add a couple of more observations:  When I got to App Registrations and take the option to expose an api, the url contains ONLY http and not api (as yours does).  The menu on the left also looks different.  It doesn't have token configurations or app roles.  If I try to run the scripts, I get a System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Cng' from assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0 ...Could not load type error as well. (if that gives you a clue)

Comment: @PeteHelgren no, I registered all AD apps manually. Not using scripts

Comment: Stanley, thanks again.  So I think I have an idea what the issue is but I need to dig deeper so I fully understand.  I created a new tenant for Azure Active Directory, rather than use my "default" directory.  And, in that process, lost some functionality.  When I use my default instance, I see the option for Admins and users.  So, I'll need to figure out how to create a new directory and not lose the function (permissions?  maybe).  I any case, thanks for the screen shots and tips.  Very helpful.

Comment: @PeteHelgren, wow, my pleasure, glad to know your issue has been solved